# vermutlich oder wahrscheinlich

Tags: word-usage, difference, adjective

Both the words "wahrscheinlich" and "vermutlich" have the same meaning in English, i.e., "probably". I heard people using both the words frequently; what should I use when?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Our not-yet implemented [tag warning](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/1110) for [tag:difference] questions asks you to show your prior research and elaborate why dictionaries did not help you. Please [edit] your post accordingly to prevent your question being closed. Check out the [help] for more information about editing, closing and other features of this site.

Answer (score 4):

A literal translation for "wahrscheinlich" is "It seems true." A similar translation for "vermutlich" is "I suspect."

They can both mean "probably," but you "get there" a slightly different way. The first is more objective, the second, subjective.